# Can I copy a folder within folders in a repository without affecting the original source

Tags: tortoisesvn

In a repository I copied bunch of folders I want to work with to a new folder in this repository. I checkout this newly created folder to my local computer.

My question is does modifying the new folder "adding files and modifying others"  affect the original folders that were copied from ?

Answer (score 0):

Copying an item in Subversion does not alter the original. The new copy has its own history which diverges from the original at the point where the copy was made.

Comment: That's what I thought, tnks